# Using :before via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the current issue: I define via CSS the current role for a `div` element

```
.divElement:before {
    background-image: url(../images/triangle.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: 62%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    width: 100px;
}

.divElement{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF8D6;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: black;
    font: 1em/1.4 Cambria,Georgia,sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 500px 3em;    
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I created this element dynamically using jQuery: `$('<div class="divElement"><p><strong></strong></p></div>').appendTo(....)` this works correctly. The issue becomes when using jQuery and I try to dynamically change the `backgroung-image` and the `top` attribute of the content before the `divElement` (which I define in CSS with `:before`)

I tried something like this for the `background-image`, but doesn't work:

```
$('.divElement:before').css('background-image', 'url(../images/triangle_reverse.png)');
```

How can I do that? Thank to all !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best solution is to keep the styling in the CSS for this one ([as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)) and simply use the `addClass` function in jQuery. Here's an example:

```
.divElement:before {
    background-image: url(../images/triangle.png);
}

.divElement.reverse:before {
    background-image: url(../images/triangle_reverse.png);
}
```

Then in jQuery all you need to is add the class `reverse` like this:

```
$('.divElement').addClass("reverse");
```

You can even easily toggle between on and off states using:

```
$('.divElement').toggleClass("reverse");
```

Comment: Just be aware that the :before pseudo-class selector does not work in IE versions earlier than IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

The following will search for all nodes with class `.divElement`, take the corresponding elements that appear *before* tem and change their background images. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

```
$('.divElement').prev().css('background-image', 'url(../images/triangle_reverse.png)');
```

Comment: thank for your immediate response and yes i try to  change the background image and top attribute of the element that appear before ...but still doesn't work...